# How to Diagnose MismatchedInputException in getForEntity()?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting this an error:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class [Llets.go.project.containers.Container;] and content type [application/stream+json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Llets.go.project.containers.Container;` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Llets.go.project.containers.Container;` out of START_OBJECT token
```

I also realized that I don't have a `Llets.go.project.containers`, only a `lets.go.project.containers`

Here is the code simplified:

```
public class Container implements Serializable
{
    private int index;
    public Container(int i) { index = i; }
    public String getIndex() { return index; }
}
```

In a test file:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    ResponseEntity<SomeObject[]> objects = this.testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/test", <What goes here?>);
}
```

In a controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> func()
{
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = response -> {
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            response.write(SerializationUtils.serialize(new Container(i)));
            response.flush();
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON).body(responseBody);
}
```

I'm unsure how to debug issues with Jackson deserialization bugs. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, where does the data come from that is being deserialized? How was it created?

Comment: Also, please try to make  sure you have a minimal, *reproducible* example. You have named a class `TestContainer`, but appear to expect its constructor to be `Container`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was trying to minimize names and forgot to take out that instance of Test from TestContainer. Anything else that can be reduced?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The `@Test` is the starting point. The data comes from the `@GetMapping` which simply makes a lot of objects, serializes them and returns them via HTTP Stream.

Comment: Do you need to use the web framework in order to cause the problem? At least, do you need to write routes explicitly? And where in the code does the deserialization happen? What [does the error message tell you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), besides just reporting the kind of problem?

Comment: Yes this only happens when trying to do internal JUnit testing. Using fetch() in Javascript on a client does not cause any issues. The route called from the `@Test` is explicit for simplicity. Reduced the post code as well for clarity.

Comment: Added complete error to post as well.